# CSS - How to make the columns equals

Tags: css

If I want my div.row3 to be equal in height, how can I code it in CSS if it changes dynamically using ajax.  Table cannot be used. (Note: My current code uses js. I want to know if it is possible using CSS)

```
<div class="gridcontainer">

        <div class="columns">
            <div class="row">
            </div> 
            <div class="row">
            </div>
            <div class="row3">
                DYNAMIC HEIGHT ROW
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="columns">
            <div class="row">
            </div> 
            <div class="row">
            </div>
            <div class="row3">
                DYNAMIC HEIGHT ROW
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="columns">
            <div class="row">
            </div> 
            <div class="row">
            </div>
            <div class="row3">
                DYNAMIC HEIGHT ROW
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=css+equal+height+columns, https://www.google.com/search?q=css+equal+height+columns – please do some research before asking!

Comment: Chris Coyier at CSS-tricks has written an extensive guide on this: http://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/

Comment: Have you considered using a table instead?

Comment: @CBroe I need to make the third row equal. The examples on the net is not the same

Comment: That’s why they are called _examples_. Once you understood the _prinicple_ you should be able to _adapt_ the technique to your specific problem.

Comment: But it is not the same principle.

Answer (score 0):

Use the table-* display :

```
.gridcontainer {
   display: table-row;
}

.columns {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/fiqetixi/1/)

Comment: I need to make the third row equal.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you have could do something with this:
http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-cross-browser-css-no-hacks

or with javascript (please choose css instead:

```
$(window).load(function(){
        //same height
        if ($(window).width() > 550) {
            $('#container').each(function(){  
                var highestBox = 0;
                $('.eq', this).each(function(){

                    if($(this).height() > highestBox) 
                       highestBox = $(this).height(); 
                });  
                $('.eq',this).height(highestBox);
            });
        }
    });
```

***update***

a CSS solution:
http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-3-column.htm

Comment: This is a terrible solution

Comment: yes, i agree with that. But like i posted, there are many ways to do this with CSS.

Comment: the js is also my previous solution. what i need is the CSS solution

Comment: you also could use try this: http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-3-column.htm (updated my answer)